# confidence level with crfsuite predictions

Tags: machine-learning, nltk

I am using the CRFSuite package here 
http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/tutorial.html

and I have successfully used it to build a classifier and tag text. However, I'm wondering if I can get a confidence value for each prediction it makes?

It doesn't seem so. What I would really like is to get the probability of a word being each type of tag ('PER', 'LOC', 'MISC', etc), rather than just the prediction itself.

Comment: have you figured out how to get the confidence score of labelings from crfsuite?

Answer (score 0):

The API provides extracting conditional probabilities. I guess you mean the crfsuite binary does not have that as option. You could edit the source and add the option yourself

Comment: any concrete steps on how to do that?

Comment: The API has the method listed. [link](https://github.com/chokkan/crfsuite/blob/master/include/crfsuite_api.hpp#L392)
You need to iterate over the all possible labels and extract the probability out.
Or just use the python interface. Its a lot easier to prototype and work using that [Python CRFSuite](https://python-crfsuite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pycrfsuite.html#tagging)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this serves as an answer.   Sklearn crfsuite provides probability for each label.

```
predict_marginals(X)
Make a prediction.

Parameters: X (list of lists of dicts) – feature dicts in python-crfsuite format
Returns:    y – predicted probabilities for each label at each position
Return type:    list of lists of dicts
```

Source: https://sklearn-crfsuite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sklearn_crfsuite/estimator.html#CRF.predict_marginals